# Sending buffered images between Java client and Twisted Python socket server

Tags: java, python, sockets, twisted

I have a server-side function that draws an image with the Python Imaging Library. The Java client requests an image, which is returned via socket and converted to a BufferedImage.

I prefix the data with the size of the image to be sent, followed by a CR. I then read this number of bytes from the socket input stream and attempt to use ImageIO to convert to a BufferedImage.

In abbreviated code for the client:

```java
public String writeAndReadSocket(String request) {
    // Write text to the socket
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
    bufferedWriter.write(request);
    bufferedWriter.flush();

    // Read text from the socket
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    // Read the prefixed size
    int size = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());

    // Get that many bytes from the stream
    char[] buf = new char[size];
    bufferedReader.read(buf, 0, size);
    return new String(buf);
}

public BufferedImage stringToBufferedImage(String imageBytes) {
    return ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes()));
}
```

and the server:

```py
# Twisted server code here

# The analog of the following method is called with the proper client
# request and the result is written to the socket.
def worker_thread():
    img = draw_function()
    buf = StringIO.StringIO()
    img.save(buf, format="PNG")
    img_string = buf.getvalue()
    return "%i\r%s" % (sys.getsizeof(img_string), img_string)
```

This works for sending and receiving Strings, but image conversion (usually) fails. **I'm trying to understand why the images are not being read properly.** My best guess is that the client is not reading the proper number of bytes, but I honestly don't know why that would be the case.

**Side notes:**

- I realize that the char[]-to-String-to-bytes-to-BufferedImage Java logic is roundabout, but reading the bytestream directly produces the same errors.
- I have a version of this working where the client socket isn't persistent, ie. the request is processed and the connection is dropped. That version works fine, as I don't need to care about the image size, but I want to learn *why* the proposed approach doesn't work.

Comment: It is usually a very bad idea to convert binary into text (so many things that can go wrong) Why don't you just send out the binary data over to your server?

Comment: You're definitely right. I work in a chemistry lab, and we historically neglect anything that doesn't directly translate to papers. I'm trying to fix that, but I'm not exactly an experienced coder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `BufferedReader.read()` isn't guaranteed to fill the buffer, and converting the image to String and back is not only pointless but wrong.
2. String is not a container for binary data, and the round-trip isn't guaranteed to work.

It would be better to redesign the protocol so that you can get rid of the `readLine()`, and send the length in binary and can read the entire stream with a `DataInputStream`.

In general when dealing with binary protocols, the answer is always `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream`, unless the byte order isn't the canonical network byte order, which is a protocol design mistake, and in which case you need to look into byte-ordered `ByteBuffers`.

Comment: This diagnosis is not correct.  He's reading the count and the image through the same buffer.  (The problem is that he's shoving binary data though the character I/O stack ... and back.)

Comment: @StephenC Agreed. He is also assuming that `bufferedReader.read(buf, 0, size)` fills the buffer.

Comment: I prepended everything with 32-bit binary and switched to `DataInputStream`. Everything works now (!), although it randomly errors ~5% of the time. 

I obviously have a lot more to learn about writing these things. Would you recommend any resources? My standard approach (ie. Google) returns a lot of contradictory advice :-(

Comment: @PattimusPrime When dealing with binary protocols, the answer is always `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream`, unless the byte order isn't the canonical network byte order, which is a protocol mistake, and in which case you need to look into byte-ordered `ByteBuffers`. I've adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the server code, your use of `sys.getsizeof` is wrong. That returns the size of the bytestring object, whereas what you want is the number of bytes in the bytestring, i.e. its length `len(img_string)`.

Also, in the client code the `.readLine` method reads characters until it sees either `'\r'` possibly followed `'\n'` or `'\n'`, so using `'\r'` as the terminator will cause a problem if the first byte of the image data happens to be 0x0A, i.e. `'\n'`.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I switched from `sys.getsizeof` to `len`, which was definitely an issue. I also got rid of the `readLine` approach.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that the problem is that you are trying to use a `Reader` and `getBytes()` to read binary data (the image).

The `Reader` stack will be taking the bytes from the underlying socket stream, converting them to characters (using the platform's default character encoding), and returning them as a String.  Then you convert the String contents back into bytes using the default encoding again.  The initial conversion of bytes to characters is likely to be "lossy" for binary data.

The fix is not to use a `Reader` / `BufferedReader`.  Use an `InputStream` and a `BufferedInputStream`.  You are not making it easy for yourself by sending the image size encoded as text, but you can deal with that by reading bytes one at a time until you get the newline, and converting them "by hand" into an integer.

(If the size was sent as a fixed-sized binary integer in "network order" you could use `DataInputStream` instead ... )

Comment: I'm obviously a novice here... could you define "network order"? Is there some convention I should be following in all of this? I'd appreciate any advice here.

Comment: @PattimusPrime See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_byte_order#Endianness_in_networking.  (Also known as big-endian order; i.e. most significant byte first.)